# Translate standard message "please fill out this field" in Elementor Form widget

Tags: wordpress, forms, messaging, elementor

I need help in editing the standard message “Please fill out this field”. I have an Arabic website and I used Elementor Form. In the elementor form, I made Name, Email and Mobile Number fields as mandatory. But when you hover over it or select Submit button without entering the values, you get the popup “Please fill out this field”. Is there a way you can translate or edit this message in Arabic?

Please note that I have already translated all the Custom Messages in Form widget in the Elementor for Wordpress.

URL: https://arabic.hydurworkshop.com/questionnaire/

Kind Regards,

Comment: best option is to use custom form validations

Comment: @Saravanan The custom messages in the form widget had the below questions - Success Message, Error Message, Required Message and Invalid Message. The Required Message was "This field is required" and I already translated this field. But i still get "Please fill out this field"

Comment: Try the loco translate plugin, you can translate strings with this, you may find those string and translate it.

Comment: @SunilNair, did you check if the locale is applied correctly?

Comment: @Saravanan yes i did. Its a separate domain of wordpress instance which is used for Arabic language. The complete website is arabic translated. but only this error message which is not. URL: https://arabic.hydurworkshop.com/questionnaire/

Comment: @Earid I installed the Loco Translate Plugin, but unfortunately the message "please fill out this field" is not appearing in the translation section. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I've made research and I found the solution,

to your to the page you have the form in, add html widget, and paste this following code in it:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("الرجاء ملء هذا الحقل");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
</script>
```

you can change the what's written between brackets on the following line(inside the apostrophe sign):
'e.target.setCustomValidity'

--
Bests
Nour